# How to copy tables from one DB to another DB Of Different server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server

I Have Two servers where we want to **copy some tables from DB1 Of one server to DB2 Of another serve on daily basis**

On DB1 We are updating database regularly

Van any one have Idia about same

Comment: You can use mysql replication for master / slave replication or you use a toll ie. pt_table_sync from percona

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Why didn't it work? Did you do any research before asking? What did you find and why didn't it work? Please have a look at SO [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to ask proper questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep both server/db in sync then best option is master/slave replication.

But if you don't want to setup replication then you can use a script, which will take dump from server1/db1 and restore on server2/db2 on daily basis, even you can avoid locking on your production server by `--single-transaction` option.

You can use below statement in your script and schedule it in less traffic hours (night) through cronjob.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction -h server1_ip -uroot -proot123 mydb1 table1 table2 table3 | mysql -h server2_ip -uroot -p root123 mydb2
```

Comment: Can I use bellow Code

mysqldump.php
<?php
mysqldump -h server1_ip -uroot -proot123 mydb1 table1 table2 table3 | mysql -h server2_ip -uroot -p root123 mydb2
?>

Cron Job 

0 0 * * * php -q /home/domainuser/public_html/mysqldump.php

Comment: make sure on which server this script exist that server user (here it is root) should be able to connect to other db server and should have proper privileges....you can add --single-transaction option to avoid locking on production server so you can use "mysqldump --single-transaction -h server1_ip -uroot -proot123 mydb1 table1 table2 table3 | mysql -h server2_ip -uroot -p root123 mydb2"

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Replication`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).

Comment: Thanks for helping me

Comment: @keshavkshirsagar, if it solves your problem, then mark is as answer.