# Copy SQL tables from one DB to DB at different server with PHP

Tags: php, sql, prestashop

I need to copy some tables from one DB to another DB at different server.

I can't use master/slave replication because in some tables I need to make some calculation (change product price based on currency), disable some products, etc.

I have working script for scenario where both DB are at the same server (it isn't the prettiest one but it worked good) but I have a problem to modify it work with two different servers (permissions are OK, at first server I can run script with simple `INSERT` and it will insert it at another one).

Below is the part of the script (here I sync tables 1 to 1):

```
/* Source */
$hostname_source = 'localhost';
$username_source = '******************';
$password_source = '******************';
$database_source = '******************';
$db_source = new mysqli($hostname_source,$username_source,$password_source,$database_source);

/* Target */
$hostname_target = 'IP_OF_THE_TARGET_SERVER';
$username_target = '******************';
$password_target = '******************';
$database_target = '******************';
$db_target = new mysqli($hostname_target,$username_target,$password_target,$database_target);

$source_db_prefix = "ps_";
$target_db_prefix = "ps_";

/* Tables to sync 1 to 1 */
$full_sync_tables = array('product', 'product_attribute', 'product_attribute_combination', 'product_attribute_image', 'product_attribute_shop', 'product_download', 'product_shop', 'product_supplier', 'category', 'category_group', 'category_product', 'category_shop', 'attribute', 'attribute_group', 'attribute_group_shop', 'attribute_impact', 'attribute_shop', 'layered_indexable_attribute_group', 'layered_product_attribute', 'feature', 'feature_product', 'feature_shop', 'feature_value', 'layered_indexable_feature', 'manufacturer', 'manufacturer_shop', 'product_supplier', 'supplier', 'supplier_shop', 'image', 'image_shop', 'product_attribute_image', 'stock_available', 'stock_mvt', 'stock_mvt_reason');

foreach ($full_sync_tables as $sync_table) {
    $db_target->query("TRUNCATE TABLE ".$target_db_prefix.$sync_table);
    $db_target->query("INSERT INTO ".$target_db_prefix.$sync_table." SELECT * FROM ".$database_source.".".$source_db_prefix.$sync_table);
    echo "End: ".$target_db_prefix.$sync_table." : ". $db_target->affected_rows."<br/>";
}
```

Script removes tables:

```
$db_target->query("TRUNCATE TABLE ".$target_db_prefix.$sync_table);
```

But he can't insert:

```
$db_target->query("INSERT INTO ".$target_db_prefix.$sync_table." SELECT * FROM ".$database_source.".".$source_db_prefix.$sync_table);
```

I suspect that there should be some kind of reference to server before $database_source but I'm not sure.

Comment: [Useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32310075/how-to-copy-tables-from-one-db-to-another-db-of-different-server)

Comment: above link may be useful to you

Comment: `$db_target` has no notion of the source database and trying to select there from `localhost` will not give you information from the source as `localhost` will the `$db_target`'s localhost.

Comment: @jeroen I understand now. But adding `SOURCE_SERVER_IP.` before `$database_source` doesn't work. Maybe because target user don't have permissions to source DB ? But I'm not sure how could I grant them? Do you have any idea how could I make this synchronization work?

@MadhuriPatel replication isn't an option for me

Comment: These connections don't have any notion of each other and most likely the user on the targer server has no (external...) access to the source database. So as far as I can see, the only way to pass the information from the source to the target, is to pass it through php.

Comment: @jeroen so, only way is to save all this informations in arrays and than write them to the target DB? But would I need to specify all columns names, etc? Could you tell me the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: @Odin It is likely that one or more tables do not have the same structure.

Comment: @Rolige I don't think so. First I updated DB manually and than run script.